# how to download files with different extension with send_file command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types, sendfile

I have the following code, I want to download files of different mime types. Ie docx, pdf etc. I have defined my download action, then bellow am trying to get the file extension for which i direct it to the correct mimetype. But this doesnot seem to work

```
def download
    @uploadedfile = Uploadedfile.find(params[:id])
    send_data(
        @uploadedfile.upload_file.path,
        :filename => @uploadedfile.name,
       # :type => 'application/pdf',          
       # :type=>"*/*",
       # :type=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",     
       #:type=> MIME::Types.type_for(@uploadedfile.name).to_s, 
       #:content_type => %w(application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document application/pdf),                   
        :type=> file_extension,
        :stream => true,     
        :x_sendfile=>true,
        :url_based_filename => true 
    )               
    flash[:notice] = "The file has been downloaded"
  end  

  def file_extension
    @uploadedfile = Uploadedfile.find(params[:id])    
   # ext = File.extname("#{@uploadedfile.name}")   
    ext = File.extname(@uploadedfile.name)
    if (ext == ".pdf")           
        content_type = "application/pdf"
     elsif (ext == ".doc") || ( ext == ".rtf") || ( ext == ".docx")
        content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
     elsif (ext == ".txt")
        content_type = "text/Plain"
     elsif (ext == ".rar")
         content_type = "Application/x-rar-compressed"
     elsif (ext == ".jpeg" || ext==".jpg")
         content_type = "image/jpeg"
     else
         content_type = "Application/octet-stream"
     end
     content_type
  end
```

but this seems not to work, where am i going wrong? Please help

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no error, all downloads simply takes Application/octet-stream regardless of the extesion

Comment: Currently what type of files are you uploading?

Comment: I have uploaded both pdf and word(docx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making a slight change on the `def file_extension`  to

```
def file_extension
    up = Uploadedfile.find(params[:id])   
    ext = File.extname("#{up.upload_file}")
    if (ext == ".pdf")           
        "application/pdf"
     elsif (ext == ".doc") || ( ext == ".rtf") || ( ext == ".docx")
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
     elsif (ext == ".txt")
        "text/Plain"
     elsif (ext == ".rar")
         "Application/x-rar-compressed"
     elsif (ext == ".jpeg" || ext==".jpg")
         "image/jpeg"
     else
        "Application/octet-stream"
     end     
  end
```

I changed this part to `ext = File.extname(@uploadedfile.name)` to  `ext = File.extname("#{up.upload_file}")` where `up = Uploadedfile.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i do this.

In config/initializers/constants.rb

```
MIME_TYPES_FROM_EXTENSION = {
  ".3dm" => "x-world/x-3dmf",
  ".3dmf" => "x-world/x-3dmf",
  ".a" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".aab" => "application/x-authorware-bin",
  ".aam" => "application/x-authorware-map",
  ".aas" => "application/x-authorware-seg",
  ".abc" => "text/vnd.abc",
  ".acgi" => "text/html",
  ".afl" => "video/animaflex",
  ".ai" => "application/postscript",
  ".aif" => "audio/aiff",
  ".aif" => "audio/x-aiff",
  ".aifc" => "audio/aiff",
  ".aifc" => "audio/x-aiff",
  ".aiff" => "audio/aiff",
  ".aiff" => "audio/x-aiff", 
   ".aim" => "application/x-aim",
  ".aip" => "text/x-audiosoft-intra",
  ".ani" => "application/x-navi-animation",
  ".aos" => "application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software",
  ".aps" => "application/mime",
  ".arc" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".arj" => "application/arj",
  ".arj" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".art" => "image/x-jg",
  ".asf" => "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".asm" => "text/x-asm",
  ".asp" => "text/asp",
  ".asx" => "application/x-mplayer2",
  ".asx" => "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".asx" => "video/x-ms-asf-plugin",
  ".au" => "audio/basic",
  ".au" => "audio/x-au",
  ".avi" => "application/x-troff-msvideo",
  ".avi" => "video/avi",
  ".avi" => "video/msvideo",
  ".avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
  ".avs" => "video/avs-video",
  ".bcpio" => "application/x-bcpio",
  ".bin" => "application/mac-binary",
  ".bin" => "application/macbinary", 
   ".bin" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".bin" => "application/x-binary",
  ".bin" => "application/x-macbinary",
  ".bm" => "image/bmp",
  ".bmp" => "image/bmp",
  ".bmp" => "image/x-windows-bmp",
  ".boo" => "application/book",
  ".book" => "application/book",
  ".boz" => "application/x-bzip2",
  ".bsh" => "application/x-bsh",
  ".bz" => "application/x-bzip",
  ".bz2" => "application/x-bzip2",
  ".c" => "text/plain",
  ".c" => "text/x-c",
  ".c++" => "text/plain",
  ".cat" => "application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat",
  ".cc" => "text/plain",
  ".cc" => "text/x-c",
  ".ccad" => "application/clariscad",
  ".cco" => "application/x-cocoa",
  ".cdf" => "application/cdf",
  ".cdf" => "application/x-cdf",
  ".cdf" => "application/x-netcdf", 
   ".cer" => "application/pkix-cert",
  ".cer" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
  ".cha" => "application/x-chat",
  ".chat" => "application/x-chat",
  ".class" => "application/java",
  ".class" => "application/java-byte-code",
  ".class" => "application/x-java-class",
  ".com" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".com" => "text/plain",
  ".conf" => "text/plain",
  ".cpio" => "application/x-cpio",
  ".cpp" => "text/x-c",
  ".cpt" => "application/mac-compactpro",
  ".cpt" => "application/x-compactpro",
  ".cpt" => "application/x-cpt",
  ".crl" => "application/pkcs-crl",
  ".crl" => "application/pkix-crl",
  ".crt" => "application/pkix-cert",
  ".crt" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
  ".crt" => "application/x-x509-user-cert",
  ".csh" => "application/x-csh",
  ".csh" => "text/x-script.csh",
  ".css" => "application/x-pointplus",
  ".css" => "text/css",
  ".cxx" => "text/plain",
  ".dcr" => "application/x-director",
  ".deepv" => "application/x-deepv",
  ".def" => "text/plain",
  ".der" => "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
  ".dif" => "video/x-dv", 
   ".dir" => "application/x-director",
  ".dl" => "video/dl",
  ".dl" => "video/x-dl",
  ".doc" => "application/msword",
  ".dot" => "application/msword",
  ".dp" => "application/commonground",
  ".drw" => "application/drafting",
  ".dump" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".dv" => "video/x-dv",
  ".dvi" => "application/x-dvi",
  ".dwf" => "drawing/x-dwf (old)",
  ".dwf" => "model/vnd.dwf",
  ".dwg" => "application/acad",
  ".dwg" => "image/vnd.dwg",
  ".dwg" => "image/x-dwg",
  ".dxf" => "application/dxf",
  ".dxf" => "image/vnd.dwg",
  ".dxf" => "image/x-dwg",
  ".dxr" => "application/x-director",
  ".el" => "text/x-script.elisp",
  ".elc" => "application/x-bytecode.elisp (compiled elisp)",
  ".elc" => "application/x-elc", 
   ".env" => "application/x-envoy",
  ".eps" => "application/postscript",
  ".es" => "application/x-esrehber",
  ".etx" => "text/x-setext",
  ".evy" => "application/envoy",
  ".evy" => "application/x-envoy",
  ".exe" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".f" => "text/plain",
  ".f" => "text/x-fortran",
  ".f77" => "text/x-fortran",
  ".f90" => "text/plain",
  ".f90" => "text/x-fortran",
  ".fdf" => "application/vnd.fdf",
  ".fif" => "application/fractals",
  ".fif" => "image/fif",
  ".fli" => "video/fli",
  ".fli" => "video/x-fli",
  ".flo" => "image/florian",
  ".flx" => "text/vnd.fmi.flexstor",
  ".fmf" => "video/x-atomic3d-feature",
  ".for" => "text/plain",
  ".for" => "text/x-fortran",
  ".fpx" => "image/vnd.fpx", 
   ".fpx" => "image/vnd.net-fpx",
  ".frl" => "application/freeloader",
  ".funk" => "audio/make",
  ".g" => "text/plain",
  ".g3" => "image/g3fax",
  ".gif" => "image/gif",
  ".gl" => "video/gl",
  ".gl" => "video/x-gl",
  ".gsd" => "audio/x-gsm",
  ".gsm" => "audio/x-gsm",
  ".gsp" => "application/x-gsp",
  ".gss" => "application/x-gss",
  ".gtar" => "application/x-gtar",
  ".gz" => "application/x-compressed",
  ".gz" => "application/x-gzip",
  ".gzip" => "application/x-gzip",
  ".gzip" => "multipart/x-gzip",
  ".h" => "text/plain",
  ".h" => "text/x-h",
  ".hdf" => "application/x-hdf",
  ".help" => "application/x-helpfile",
  ".hgl" => "application/vnd.hp-hpgl",
  ".hh" => "text/plain",
  ".hh" => "text/x-h",
  ".hlb" => "text/x-script",
  ".hlp" => "application/hlp",
  ".hlp" => "application/x-helpfile",
  ".hlp" => "application/x-winhelp",
  ".hpg" => "application/vnd.hp-hpgl",
  ".hpgl" => "application/vnd.hp-hpgl",
  ".hqx" => "application/binhex",
  ".hqx" => "application/binhex4",
  ".hqx" => "application/mac-binhex",
  ".hqx" => "application/mac-binhex40",
  ".hqx" => "application/x-binhex40",
  ".hqx" => "application/x-mac-binhex40",
  ".hta" => "application/hta",
  ".htc" => "text/x-component",
  ".htm" => "text/html",
  ".html" => "text/html",
  ".htmls" => "text/html",
  ".htt" => "text/webviewhtml",
  ".htx" => "text/html",
  ".ice" => "x-conference/x-cooltalk",
  ".ico" => "image/x-icon",
  ".idc" => "text/plain",
  ".ief" => "image/ief",
  ".iefs" => "image/ief",
  ".iges" => "application/iges",
  ".iges" => "model/iges",
  ".igs" => "application/iges",
  ".igs" => "model/iges",
  ".ima" => "application/x-ima",
  ".imap" => "application/x-httpd-imap",
  ".inf" => "application/inf",
  ".ins" => "application/x-internett-signup",
  ".ip" => "application/x-ip2",
  ".isu" => "video/x-isvideo",
  ".it" => "audio/it",
  ".iv" => "application/x-inventor",
  ".ivr" => "i-world/i-vrml",
  ".ivy" => "application/x-livescreen",
  ".jam" => "audio/x-jam",
  ".jav" => "text/plain",
  ".jav" => "text/x-java-source",
  ".java" => "text/plain",
  ".java" => "text/x-java-source",
  ".jcm" => "application/x-java-commerce",
  ".jfif" => "image/jpeg",
  ".jfif" => "image/pjpeg",
  ".jfif-tbnl" => "image/jpeg", 
   ".jpe" => "image/jpeg",
  ".jpe" => "image/pjpeg",
  ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".jpeg" => "image/pjpeg",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".jpg" => "image/pjpeg",
  ".jps" => "image/x-jps",
  ".js" => "application/x-javascript",
  ".jut" => "image/jutvision",
  ".kar" => "audio/midi",
  ".kar" => "music/x-karaoke",
  ".ksh" => "application/x-ksh",
  ".ksh" => "text/x-script.ksh",
  ".la" => "audio/nspaudio",
  ".la" => "audio/x-nspaudio",
  ".lam" => "audio/x-liveaudio",
  ".latex" => "application/x-latex",
  ".lha" => "application/lha",
  ".lha" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".lha" => "application/x-lha",
  ".lhx" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".list" => "text/plain",
  ".lma" => "audio/nspaudio",
  ".lma" => "audio/x-nspaudio",
  ".log" => "text/plain",
  ".lsp" => "application/x-lisp",
  ".lsp" => "text/x-script.lisp",
  ".lst" => "text/plain",
  ".lsx" => "text/x-la-asf",
  ".ltx" => "application/x-latex",
  ".lzh" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".lzh" => "application/x-lzh",
  ".lzx" => "application/lzx",
  ".lzx" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".lzx" => "application/x-lzx",
  ".m" => "text/plain",
  ".m" => "text/x-m",
  ".m1v" => "video/mpeg",
  ".m2a" => "audio/mpeg",
  ".m2v" => "video/mpeg",
  ".m3u" => "audio/x-mpequrl",
  ".man" => "application/x-troff-man",
  ".map" => "application/x-navimap",
  ".mar" => "text/plain",
  ".mbd" => "application/mbedlet",
  ".mc$" => "application/x-magic-cap-package-1.0",
  ".mcd" => "application/mcad",
  ".mcd" => "application/x-mathcad",
  ".mcf" => "image/vasa",
  ".mcf" => "text/mcf",
  ".mcp" => "application/netmc",
  ".me" => "application/x-troff-me",
  ".mht" => "message/rfc822",
  ".mhtml" => "message/rfc822",
  ".mid" => "application/x-midi",
  ".mid" => "audio/midi",
  ".mid" => "audio/x-mid",
  ".mid" => "audio/x-midi",
  ".mid" => "music/crescendo",
  ".mid" => "x-music/x-midi",
  ".midi" => "application/x-midi",
  ".midi" => "audio/midi",
  ".midi" => "audio/x-mid",
  ".midi" => "audio/x-midi",
  ".midi" => "music/crescendo",
  ".midi" => "x-music/x-midi",
  ".mif" => "application/x-frame",
  ".mif" => "application/x-mif",
  ".mime" => "message/rfc822",
  ".mime" => "www/mime",
  ".mjf" => "audio/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mjuicemediafile",
  ".mjpg" => "video/x-motion-jpeg",
  ".mm" => "application/base64",
  ".mm" => "application/x-meme",
  ".mme" => "application/base64",
  ".mod" => "audio/mod",
  ".mod" => "audio/x-mod",
  ".moov" => "video/quicktime",
  ".mov" => "video/quicktime",
  ".movie" => "video/x-sgi-movie",
  ".mp2" => "audio/mpeg",
  ".mp2" => "audio/x-mpeg",
  ".mp2" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mp2" => "video/x-mpeg",
  ".mp2" => "video/x-mpeq2a",
  ".mp3" => "audio/mpeg3", 
  ".mp3" => "audio/x-mpeg-3",
  ".mp3" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mp3" => "video/x-mpeg",
  ".mpa" => "audio/mpeg",
  ".mpa" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mpc" => "application/x-project",
  ".mpe" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mpg" => "audio/mpeg",
  ".mpg" => "video/mpeg",
  ".mpga" => "audio/mpeg",
  ".mpp" => "application/vnd.ms-project",
  ".mpt" => "application/x-project",
  ".mpv" => "application/x-project",
  ".mpx" => "application/x-project",
  ".mrc" => "application/marc",
  ".ms" => "application/x-troff-ms",
  ".mv" => "video/x-sgi-movie",
  ".my" => "audio/make",
  ".mzz" => "application/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mzz",
  ".nap" => "image/naplps",
  ".naplps" => "image/naplps",
  ".nc" => "application/x-netcdf",
  ".ncm" => "application/vnd.nokia.configuration-message",
  ".nif" => "image/x-niff",
  ".niff" => "image/x-niff",
  ".nix" => "application/x-mix-transfer",
  ".nsc" => "application/x-conference",
  ".nvd" => "application/x-navidoc",
  ".o" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".oda" => "application/oda",
  ".omc" => "application/x-omc",
  ".omcd" => "application/x-omcdatamaker",
  ".omcr" => "application/x-omcregerator",
  ".p" => "text/x-pascal",
  ".p10" => "application/pkcs10",
  ".p10" => "application/x-pkcs10",
  ".p12" => "application/pkcs-12",
  ".p12" => "application/x-pkcs12",
  ".p7a" => "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
  ".p7c" => "application/pkcs7-mime",
  ".p7c" => "application/x-pkcs7-mime", 
  ".p7m" => "application/pkcs7-mime",
  ".p7m" => "application/x-pkcs7-mime",
  ".p7r" => "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
  ".p7s" => "application/pkcs7-signature",
  ".part" => "application/pro_eng",
  ".pas" => "text/pascal",
  ".pbm" => "image/x-portable-bitmap",
  ".pcl" => "application/vnd.hp-pcl",
  ".pcl" => "application/x-pcl",
  ".pct" => "image/x-pict",
  ".pcx" => "image/x-pcx",
  ".pdb" => "chemical/x-pdb",
  ".pdf" => "application/pdf",
  ".pfunk" => "audio/make",
  ".pfunk" => "audio/make.my.funk",
  ".pgm" => "image/x-portable-graymap",
  ".pgm" => "image/x-portable-greymap",
  ".pic" => "image/pict",
  ".pict" => "image/pict",
  ".pkg" => "application/x-newton-compatible-pkg",
  ".pko" => "application/vnd.ms-pki.pko",
  ".pl" => "text/plain",
  ".pl" => "text/x-script.perl",
  ".plx" => "application/x-pixclscript",
  ".pm" => "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".pm" => "text/x-script.perl-module",
  ".pm4" => "application/x-pagemaker", 
  ".pm5" => "application/x-pagemaker",
  ".png" => "image/png",
  ".pnm" => "application/x-portable-anymap",
  ".pnm" => "image/x-portable-anymap",
  ".pot" => "application/mspowerpoint",
  ".pot" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".pov" => "model/x-pov",
  ".ppa" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".ppm" => "image/x-portable-pixmap",
  ".pps" => "application/mspowerpoint",
  ".pps" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".ppt" => "application/mspowerpoint",
  ".ppt" => "application/powerpoint",
  ".ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
  ".ppt" => "application/x-mspowerpoint",
  ".ppz" => "application/mspowerpoint",
  ".pre" => "application/x-freelance",
  ".prt" => "application/pro_eng",
  ".ps" => "application/postscript",
  ".psd" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".pvu" => "paleovu/x-pv",
  ".pwz" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", 
  ".py" => "text/x-script.phyton",
  ".pyc" => "applicaiton/x-bytecode.python",
  ".qcp" => "audio/vnd.qcelp",
  ".qd3" => "x-world/x-3dmf",
  ".qd3d" => "x-world/x-3dmf",
  ".qif" => "image/x-quicktime",
  ".qt" => "video/quicktime",
  ".qtc" => "video/x-qtc",
  ".qti" => "image/x-quicktime",
  ".qtif" => "image/x-quicktime",
  ".ra" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
  ".ra" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
  ".ra" => "audio/x-realaudio",
  ".ram" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
  ".ras" => "application/x-cmu-raster",
  ".ras" => "image/cmu-raster",
  ".ras" => "image/x-cmu-raster",
  ".rast" => "image/cmu-raster",
  ".rexx" => "text/x-script.rexx",
  ".rf" => "image/vnd.rn-realflash",
  ".rgb" => "image/x-rgb",
  ".rm" => "application/vnd.rn-realmedia",
  ".rm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
  ".rmi" => "audio/mid",
  ".rmm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
  ".rmp" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
  ".rmp" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
  ".rng" => "application/ringing-tones",
  ".rng" => "application/vnd.nokia.ringing-tone",
  ".rnx" => "application/vnd.rn-realplayer", 
  ".roff" => "application/x-troff",
  ".rp" => "image/vnd.rn-realpix",
  ".rpm" => "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
  ".rt" => "text/richtext",
  ".rt" => "text/vnd.rn-realtext",
  ".rtf" => "application/rtf",
  ".rtf" => "application/x-rtf",
  ".rtf" => "text/richtext",
  ".rtx" => "application/rtf",
  ".rtx" => "text/richtext",
  ".rv" => "video/vnd.rn-realvideo",
  ".s" => "text/x-asm",
  ".s3m" => "audio/s3m",
  ".saveme" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".sbk" => "application/x-tbook",
  ".scm" => "application/x-lotusscreencam",
  ".scm" => "text/x-script.guile",
  ".scm" => "text/x-script.scheme",
  ".scm" => "video/x-scm",
  ".sdml" => "text/plain",
  ".sdp" => "application/sdp",
  ".sdp" => "application/x-sdp",
  ".sdr" => "application/sounder",
  ".sea" => "application/sea",
  ".sea" => "application/x-sea",
  ".set" => "application/set",
  ".sgm" => "text/sgml",
  ".sgm" => "text/x-sgml",
  ".sgml" => "text/sgml",
  ".sgml" => "text/x-sgml",
  ".sh" => "application/x-bsh",
  ".sh" => "application/x-sh",
  ".sh" => "application/x-shar",
  ".sh" => "text/x-script.sh",
  ".shar" => "application/x-bsh",
  ".shar" => "application/x-shar", 
  ".shtml" => "text/html",
  ".shtml" => "text/x-server-parsed-html",
  ".sid" => "audio/x-psid",
  ".sit" => "application/x-sit",
  ".sit" => "application/x-stuffit",
  ".skd" => "application/x-koan",
  ".skm" => "application/x-koan",
  ".skp" => "application/x-koan",
  ".skt" => "application/x-koan",
  ".sl" => "application/x-seelogo",
  ".smi" => "application/smil",
  ".smil" => "application/smil",
  ".snd" => "audio/basic",
  ".snd" => "audio/x-adpcm",
  ".sol" => "application/solids",
  ".spc" => "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
  ".spc" => "text/x-speech",
  ".spl" => "application/futuresplash",
  ".spr" => "application/x-sprite",
  ".sprite" => "application/x-sprite", 
  ".src" => "application/x-wais-source",
  ".ssi" => "text/x-server-parsed-html",
  ".ssm" => "application/streamingmedia",
  ".sst" => "application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore",
  ".step" => "application/step",
  ".stl" => "application/sla",
  ".stl" => "application/vnd.ms-pki.stl",
  ".stl" => "application/x-navistyle",
  ".stp" => "application/step",
  ".sv4cpio" => "application/x-sv4cpio",
  ".sv4crc" => "application/x-sv4crc",
  ".svf" => "image/vnd.dwg",
  ".svf" => "image/x-dwg",
  ".svr" => "application/x-world",
  ".svr" => "x-world/x-svr",
  ".swf" => "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  ".t" => "application/x-troff",
  ".talk" => "text/x-speech",
  ".tar" => "application/x-tar", 
  ".tbk" => "application/toolbook",
  ".tbk" => "application/x-tbook",
  ".tcl" => "application/x-tcl",
  ".tcl" => "text/x-script.tcl",
  ".tcsh" => "text/x-script.tcsh",
  ".tex" => "application/x-tex",
  ".texi" => "application/x-texinfo",
  ".texinfo" => "application/x-texinfo",
  ".text" => "application/plain",
  ".text" => "text/plain",
  ".tgz" => "application/gnutar",
  ".tgz" => "application/x-compressed",
  ".tif" => "image/tiff",
  ".tif" => "image/x-tiff",
  ".tiff" => "image/tiff",
  ".tiff" => "image/x-tiff",
  ".tr" => "application/x-troff",
  ".tsi" => "audio/tsp-audio",
  ".tsp" => "application/dsptype",
  ".tsp" => "audio/tsplayer",
  ".tsv" => "text/tab-separated-values",
  ".turbot" => "image/florian",
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".uil" => "text/x-uil",
  ".uni" => "text/uri-list",
  ".unis" => "text/uri-list",
  ".unv" => "application/i-deas",
  ".uri" => "text/uri-list",
  ".uris" => "text/uri-list",
  ".ustar" => "application/x-ustar",
  ".ustar" => "multipart/x-ustar",
  ".uu" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".uu" => "text/x-uuencode",
  ".uue" => "text/x-uuencode",
  ".vcd" => "application/x-cdlink", 
  ".vcs" => "text/x-vcalendar",
  ".vda" => "application/vda",
  ".vdo" => "video/vdo",
  ".vew" => "application/groupwise",
  ".viv" => "video/vivo",
  ".viv" => "video/vnd.vivo",
  ".vivo" => "video/vivo",
  ".vivo" => "video/vnd.vivo",
  ".vmd" => "application/vocaltec-media-desc",
  ".vmf" => "application/vocaltec-media-file",
  ".voc" => "audio/voc",
  ".voc" => "audio/x-voc",
  ".vos" => "video/vosaic",
  ".vox" => "audio/voxware",
  ".vqe" => "audio/x-twinvq-plugin",
  ".vqf" => "audio/x-twinvq",
  ".vql" => "audio/x-twinvq-plugin",
  ".vrml" => "application/x-vrml",
  ".vrml" => "model/vrml",
  ".vrml" => "x-world/x-vrml",
  ".vrt" => "x-world/x-vrt",
  ".vsd" => "application/x-visio",
  ".vst" => "application/x-visio",
  ".vsw" => "application/x-visio",
  ".w60" => "application/wordperfect6.0", 
  ".w61" => "application/wordperfect6.1",
  ".w6w" => "application/msword",
  ".wav" => "audio/wav",
  ".wav" => "audio/x-wav",
  ".wb1" => "application/x-qpro",
  ".wbmp" => "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
  ".web" => "application/vnd.xara",
  ".wiz" => "application/msword",
  ".wk1" => "application/x-123",
  ".wmf" => "windows/metafile",
  ".wml" => "text/vnd.wap.wml",
  ".wmlc" => "application/vnd.wap.wmlc",
  ".wmls" => "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript",
  ".wmlsc" => "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc",
  ".word" => "application/msword",
  ".wp" => "application/wordperfect",
  ".wp5" => "application/wordperfect",
  ".wp5" => "application/wordperfect6.0",
  ".wp6" => "application/wordperfect",
  ".wpd" => "application/wordperfect",
  ".wpd" => "application/x-wpwin",
  ".wq1" => "application/x-lotus",
  ".wri" => "application/mswrite",
  ".wri" => "application/x-wri",
  ".wrl" => "application/x-world",
  ".wrl" => "model/vrml",
  ".wrl" => "x-world/x-vrml", 
  ".wrz" => "model/vrml",
  ".wrz" => "x-world/x-vrml",
  ".wsc" => "text/scriplet",
  ".wsrc" => "application/x-wais-source",
  ".wtk" => "application/x-wintalk",
  ".xbm" => "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xbm" => "image/x-xbm",
  ".xbm" => "image/xbm",
  ".xdr" => "video/x-amt-demorun",
  ".xgz" => "xgl/drawing",
  ".xif" => "image/vnd.xiff",
  ".xl" => "application/excel",
  ".xla" => "application/excel",
  ".xla" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xla" => "application/x-msexcel",
  ".xlb" => "application/excel",
  ".xlb" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xlb" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlc" => "application/excel",
  ".xlc" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xlc" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xld" => "application/excel",
  ".xld" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlk" => "application/excel",
  ".xlk" => "application/x-excel", 
  ".xll" => "application/excel",
  ".xll" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xll" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlm" => "application/excel",
  ".xlm" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xlm" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xls" => "application/excel",
  ".xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xls" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xls" => "application/x-msexcel",
  ".xlt" => "application/excel",
  ".xlt" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlv" => "application/excel",
  ".xlv" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlw" => "application/excel",
  ".xlw" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  ".xlw" => "application/x-excel",
  ".xlw" => "application/x-msexcel",
  ".xm" => "audio/xm", 
  ".xml" => "application/xml",
  ".xml" => "text/xml",
  ".xmz" => "xgl/movie",
  ".xpix" => "application/x-vnd.ls-xpix",
  ".xpm" => "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xpm" => "image/xpm",
  ".x-png" => "image/png",
  ".xsr" => "video/x-amt-showrun",
  ".xwd" => "image/x-xwd",
  ".xwd" => "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".xyz" => "chemical/x-pdb",
  ".z" => "application/x-compress",
  ".z" => "application/x-compressed",
  ".zip" => "application/x-compressed",
  ".zip" => "application/x-zip-compressed",
  ".zip" => "application/zip",
  ".zip" => "multipart/x-zip",
  ".zoo" => "application/octet-stream",
  ".zsh" => "text/x-script.zsh"
}
```

In lib/core_extensions.rb - this needs to be required somewhere in your config.

```
class File
  def self.guess_filetype(filename)
    `file --mime -b "#{filename}"`.split(";").first || MIME_TYPES_FROM_EXTENSION[File.extname(filename)]
  end
end
```

Finally, in the controller, using your example, in the send_file call, i would do

```
:type=> File.guess_filetype(@uploadedfile.name)
```

The guess_filetype method makes a shell call to `file`, which is a command line utility.  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)

If `file` can't get the mimetype (it usually does, it's pretty good), then i fall back to my massive list of known mime types from extension, stored in that constant.

The reason i do `file` first, rather than just rely on the list of extensions, is that `file` looks inside the actual content of the file itself, so if somebody renamed a file's extension, `file` wouldn't be fooled: it would still know what mime type to return.

Comment: You seem to have all available MIME Types. That's great :)

Comment: i did call `class File
  def self.guess_filetype(filename)
    `file --mime -b "#{filename}"`.split(";").first || MIME_TYPES_FROM_EXTENSION[File.extname(filename)]
  end
end` in `enviroment.rb` other file types seem to work well; pdf, jpeg, but doc and docx, xls dont work. Have i missed something?

Comment: MIME_TYPES_FROM_EXTENSION[File.extname(filename)] seems not to work, I have tried to use it alone and i get an error `:type option required`

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean that if you do `MIME_TYPES_FROM_EXTENSION[".xls"]` you get `nil` back?  Provide some details please.